# Simple Web API Calculator Assistance

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

I am doing a class on ASP.Net and I need to make a Web Api that does a calculation.  I can get it to work for the Addition, but when I try to do other functions, I can't get them to work.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but I have no clue.  Can someone give me some help?

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPICalc.Models
{
    public class Calc
    {
        public float Add(float fn, float sn)
        { return (sn + fn); }

        public float Sub(float fn, float sn)
        { return (sn - fn); }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPICalc.Models;

namespace WebAPICalc.Controllers
{
    public class CalcController : ApiController
    {
        Calc oCalc = new Calc();

        [Route("api/calc/add/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]

        public float Get(float paramOne, float paramTwo)
        {
             return oCalc.Add(paramOne, paramTwo);

        }
        [Route("api/calc/sub/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]
         public IHttpActionResult GetSub(float paramOne, float paramTwo)
         {
             return Ok(oCalc.Sub(paramOne, paramTwo));
         }

         }
     }
```

View:

```
<h2>Mycalc</h2>

<input type="text" id="fn" size="5" />
<input type="text" id="sn" size="5" />
<input type="text" id="tn" size="5" />
<input type="button" value="add" onclick="add();" />
<input type="button" value="sub" onclick="sub();" />



<script>

        function add() {
            alert("here api/calc/add/ " + fn.value + " /" + sn.value)
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/calc/add/" + fn.value + "/" + sn.value,
                //url: "api/calc/add/5/7",
                cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                    alert(html)
                    tn.value = html
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
    }

    function sub() {
        alert("here api/calc/sub/ " + fn.value + " /" + sn.value)
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/calc/sub/" + fn.value + "/" + sn.value,
            //url: "api/calc/sub/5/7",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                alert(html)
                tn.value = html
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `I can't get them to work` what does it mean? What problem you are facing?

Comment: I get a 404 error in the return for either of the buttons if I add in the subtract.  If I just do the add, it works, and I get the result without the 404.  So I'm not sure what the difference is once I'm adding the subtract button and function to be called in the script

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u didn't forget this line

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

in the WebApiConfig file

i am suspecting that ur api can't see the attribute routing and just responding to the default routing and the default get action which is currently doing the add operation , u can also comment the add action and check what will happen to confirm that

Comment: I was hoping that was it, but that is in the WebApiConfig file it seems.  Thanks though!  Good thought!

Answer (score 0):

Web API and API controllers hardly pay any attention to the name of the action in the controllers. So the two actions Get and GetSub are pretty much the same because the parameters list are identical and the return values are pretty much the same as well. hence the reason for Get works on its own, but blows up when you and the GetSub.

My suggestion is, for simple binary operators, just send a string like "2 + 4" or "19 * 5.67" to a "Get" in the controller. And create a private helper function in your controller called Evaluate to evaluate these 
simple expressions by checking and finding whether the numbers are added, subtracted, multiplied or divided and then completes the calculation and return the result to the "Get" Action which will in turn send it to your client.

For more complicated expressions, you need to create an "Expression Parser" which can handle more complicated expressions and calculates their values. This one is a great challenge.

Hope this helps.